# How can I add a 'Delete Car' button to my Roblox Car Spawner?

Tags: roblox

Need help with a Car Spawner

I have created a Car Spawner, and it works. But, what I want to do is to add a 'Delete Car' button, where if I click on it and I have spawned any car, it will despawn the car. Sadly, I don't know how I can do this.

I tried finding forums, but they didn't have the answer(they did but not in a way I wanted). I also tried finding tutorials on YouTube, but they were not in a way I wanted as well.

Comment: @IGOTTHIS1551 My cars are located in `game.workspace.ServerStorage.Cars` and I need a script that will despawn every car the player has spawned

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I did this correct I'm new to LUA

```
local button = script.Parent
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local car = -- ||PUT THE CAR'S INSTANCE OR REFERENCE||
    if car then
        car:Destroy()
        print("Car deleted!")
    else
        print("Car not found!")
    end
end)
```

Comment: I'm new to LUA as well but what do you mean by 'instance' or 'reference'

Comment: Do you mean where the car(s) are located e.g. `game.workspace.Carname`?

Comment: Yes so if your car is in that workspace so put the name

Comment: The script isn't working

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

assume you have a car named "car" in workspace and you have a brick called "button" which includes a ClickDetector named "ClickDetector", and you have a script in "button":

```
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    workspace.car:Destroy()
end)
```